# keystonejs with docker on Ubuntu issue node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, keystonejs

I have an issue when I want to build/start my keystonejs app on docker-compose.
I am getting this error saying that it cannot find node-sass@4.5.0. And I noticed before that it shows other error messages related this:

> kerberos.target.mk:105: recipe for target
>   'Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o' failed

```
Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
.
.
.
.
.
binding.target.mk:121: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.12-x86_64-linode105
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-09-08T14_25_16_550Z-debug.log
```

My Dockerfile is here:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ “npm”, “start” ]
```

And here is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the node-sass version to node-sass@4.5.3 and it worked. I read this comment on node-sass github. Someone reported a similar issue.